# Need JS code for Azure Forms Recognizer rest api

Tags: azure, azure-form-recognizer

i am using ocr labelling tool for scanning the invoices .i am able to get the output in json and csv but i have it to achieve it via JS code.

my url is `https://xxxxxxxx.cognitiveservices.azure.com/formrecognizer/v2.1/prebuilt/invoice/analyze?includeTextDetails=true`

as a result i need to store the result in a json file.
Using python i am able to do it but i need to have java script code or postman also will help.

VIA postman:

```
headers Content-Type application/pdf
Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key : my form recognizer key
the url :https://xxxxxxxx.cognitiveservices.azure.com/formrecognizer/v2.1/prebuilt/invoice/analyze?includeTextDetails=true"
```

i am stuck how to pass the body with file path.

ex json output of my JS code would be (it is same as labelling tool output):

```
      {"status": "succeeded",
      "createdDateTime": "2022-01-24T23:19:53Z",
      "lastUpdatedDateTime": "2022-01-24T23:19:56Z",
      "analyzeResult": {
      "version": "2.1.1",
      "readResults": [
      "pageResults": [
      "documentResults": [
                  }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Form Recognizer JavaScript SDK ([see docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/applied-ai-services/form-recognizer/how-to-guides/try-sdk-rest-api?pivots=programming-language-javascript)).

In Postman, for the POST call, please select Body: "binary" and click "Select File". Also, set Header "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream".

Sample CURL command is below:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://xxxxxxxx.cognitiveservices.azure.com/formrecognizer/v2.1/prebuilt/invoice/analyze?includeTextDetails=true' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' \
--header 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: xxxx' \
--data-binary '@/C:/temp/testinvoice.pdf'
```